# Understanding a function definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given: $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \wp(\mathbb{N})$

$\wp(\mathbb{N})$ is the power-set of $\mathbb{N}$.

Yet, when $\wp(\mathbb{N})$ comes within the definition of $f$, is it necessarily representing the set of **all permutations** of $\mathbb{N}$, or it can also be a "partial set" of the power-set. for example:$\{ \{ 1\} ,\{ 1,2\} ,\{ 42\} ,\{ 10,100,100\} \}$

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\wp(\mathbb{N})$ (I'd write that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, by the way) always means the whole powerset of $\mathbb{N}$. But since the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ is strictly smaller than the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, it follows that $f$ cannot be surjective. But that's not a problem - nothing prevents you from specifying an arbitrarily large codomain for a function...